# How to generate a tree with 500 nodes unbalanced in C#

Tags: c#

I am still new to the programming.

I am adding nodes manually inside a tree. How can I generate a tree with 500 or 1000 nodes unbalanced? Maybe with 15 levels and will that be possible to generate every time to run the program. It will generate a different tree. Maybe more in height or width.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Model.Trees;

/* Adding nodes manully to the tree*/
namespace UserInterface.Samples
{


    public abstract class SampleTree1
    {

        public static Tree TreeSample()
        {
            var tree = new Tree();
            var root = new Node("Burgle House");
            Node node1 = new Node(" Defeat Door security");
            Node node2 = new Node(" Open front OR back doors ");
            Node node3 = new Node(" Open Door using gift card or credit card");
            Node node4 = new Node(" using trees");
            Node node5 = new Node(" Enter via Windows ");
            Node node6 = new Node(" Cover the window in duct tape and gently shatter the enti");
            Node node7 = new Node(" Garage Attack ");
            Node node8 = new Node(" Enter Garage ");
            Node node9 = new Node(" Open car door ");
            Node node10 = new Node(" Brutal Force on the Garage Door)");
            Node node11 = new Node(" Put Door opener code");
            Node node12 = new Node(" EavesDrop opener code)");
            Node node13 = new Node(" Steal opener from Car)");
            Node node14 = new Node(" Cut the hole in the wall or roof ");
            Node node15 = new Node(" Penitrate House ");
            Node node16 = new Node(" Open passger door ");
            Node node17 = new Node("break Down the passanger door");
            Node node18 = new Node(" Pick lock");
            Node node19 = new Node(" Steal Keys");
            Node node20 = new Node(" Cut the hole in the wall or roof ");
            Node node21 = new Node(" Cut the wall or roof ");
            Node node22 = new Node(" Chimney attack ");
            Node node23 = new Node(" Tunnel through the floor ");
            Node node24 = new Node(" Social engineering ");
            Node node25 = new Node(" A bomb blast");
            Node node26 = new Node(" Call a locksmith");

            /*Add nodes to the tree*/

            tree.AddNode(root, null);
            tree.AddNode(node1, root);
            tree.AddNode(node2, node1);
            tree.AddNode(node3, node1);
            tree.AddNode(node4, root);
            tree.AddNode(node5, root);
            tree.AddNode(node6, node5);
            tree.AddNode(node7, root);
            tree.AddNode(node8, node7);
            tree.AddNode(node9, node8);
            tree.AddNode(node10, node9);
            tree.AddNode(node11, node9);
            tree.AddNode(node12, node11);
            tree.AddNode(node13, node11);
            tree.AddNode(node14, node8);
            tree.AddNode(node15, node7);
            tree.AddNode(node16, node15);
            tree.AddNode(node17, node16);
            tree.AddNode(node18, node16);
            tree.AddNode(node19, node16);
            tree.AddNode(node20, node15);
            tree.AddNode(node21, root);
            tree.AddNode(node22, root);
            tree.AddNode(node23, root);
            tree.AddNode(node24, root);
            tree.AddNode(node25, root);
            tree.AddNode(node26, root);

            return tree;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: -1 Just use `Random` in a for-loop

Answer (score 1):

Since it is just past Christmas. This should get you going.
You'll just need to tweak it to suit your needs.

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    private List<Node> children = new List<Node>();

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Add(Node child)
    {
        children.Add(child);
    }

    public void Print(string prefix)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prefix + Name);
        prefix = "-" + prefix;
        foreach (var child in children) child.Print(prefix);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static Random  random = new Random();

    public static Node CreateBranch(int depth, int maxDepth, int maxWidth)
    {            
        if (depth > maxDepth) return null;
        var node = new Node(Path.GetRandomFileName());
        int width = random.Next(maxWidth);
        depth++;
        for (var i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
            var child = CreateBranch(depth, maxDepth, maxWidth);
            if (child != null) node.Add(child);
        }
        return node;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var node = CreateBranch(0, 5, 5);
        node.Print("");
    }
}
```